# Is it normal to have repetitive CSS declarations when using frameworks?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks

I'm developing a Wordpress theme and I am using the Bootstrap framework. One of the styles in the Bootstrap CSS file is:

```
input,
textarea,
.uneditable-input {
  width: 206px;
}
```

It's affecting my search button, so in my CSS file I'm going to have to re-declare its style as width: auto;. I'm just wondering if this is a standard practice, or if there is a better way as to implement such frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes when you are using CSS frameworks, you will have to override unwanted styles by duplicating the styles. You can ofcourse edit the original CSS in the framework, however you'll lose those changes when upgrading to a newer version. In case of Bootstrap you can edit the LESS file and generate a new CSS

Comment: Thanks. I'm by no means a professional developer/designer so I'm not familiar with the "standard practices". Glad to know that my way is considered "normal".